# Assigning an Outlook Task in C#

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I have tried 2 approaches to achieve the end of being able to create and send an Outlook Task, both error out in a way that I am unable to resolve on my own.

I'm having trouble creating an Outlook Task using Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library and the How To from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184639.aspx

The first line of this code creates an Outlook.TaskItem:

```
Outlook.TaskItem task = Application.CreateItem(
    Outlook.OlItemType.olTaskItem) as Outlook.TaskItem;
```

The "Application.CreateItem" throws an error:

```
    'System.Windows.Forms.Application' does not contain a definition for 'CreateItem'
```

Instead of System.Window.Forms.Application, I think the class it is looking for is in the Outlook.ApplicationClass, but this doesn't work either.

Hence the second attempt to replace the above code with the code is below to create the TaskItem:

```
Outlook.ApplicationClass app = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();
Outlook.TaskItem tsk = (Outlook.TaskItem) 
         app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olTaskItem);
```

The error I get is:

```
    Interop type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.
```

I'm still learning C# and am not sure how to resolve either of these errors. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If outlook is already running add the following method in your class:

```
   public static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application GetActiveOutlookApplication()
   {
      return ( Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application )System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject( "Outlook.Application" );
   }
```

... Then to use it

```
Outlook.Application app = GetActiveOutlookApplication();
Outlook.TaskItem tsk = (Outlook.TaskItem)  app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olTaskItem);
```

... For a new instance of outlook you may be able to try (not sure if this works)

```
 Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
 Outlook.TaskItem tsk = ( Outlook.TaskItem )app.CreateItem( Outlook.OlItemType.olTaskItem );
```